# T test in R and problems with run

Tags: r, t-test

When I want to make a t- test in result console gives me feedback:
Błąd w poleceniu 'var(x)':Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct.
Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.
Dodatkowo: Komunikat ostrzegawczy:
W poleceniu 'mean.default(x)': argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R, there is a type of data called `factor`.

Consider the following two sets of data:

```
set1 <- round(rnorm(10,5,2))
set1
 [1] 6 3 4 5 7 3 5 7 5 7
set2 <- round(rnorm(10,10,2))
set2
 [1] 11  9  5 11 11 10  9  7  8  9
```

You can perform a t-test as follows:

```
t.test(set1,set2)
    Welch Two Sample t-test
data:  set1 and set2
t = -4.8347, df = 17.147, p-value = 0.0001515
```

Now see what happens if we convert both sets to factors:

```
set1 <- as.factor(set1)
set2 <- as.factor(set2)
set1
[1] 6 3 4 5 7 3 5 7 5 7
Levels: 3 4 5 6 7
```

You can see that `set1` has now become the same numbers but with a collection of levels.

```
levels(set1)
[1] "3" "4" "5" "6" "7"
```

This can save a lot of space for long repetitive character levels, and can help clarify meaning in statistical analysis.

However, when you try to convert between factors and numeric representations, potentially surprising things can happen:

```
as.integer(set1)
 [1] 4 1 2 3 5 1 3 5 3 5
```

In this case, we got the factor level number for each element.

Thus, because of increased risk of unexpected results, this does not work:

```
t.test(set1,set2)
Error in var(x) : Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct.
```